# Group homomorphisms on finite groups

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Suppose there exists a homomorphism from a finite group $G$ onto $G'$, and that $G'$ has an element of order $n$. How do we prove that $G$ has an element of order $n$?

(From Lagrange's Theorem, we know that the order of an element must divide the order of a group. And also homomorphisms have this property that the order of an element's image must divide the order of the element.)

Comment: Hint: what can we say about the order of an element that maps to the element of order $n$?

Comment: That it is a multiple of n? Because, as I said, the order of the image of an element must divide the order of the element.

Comment: Yes, and if you have an element $g$ of order $nk$, how can can you get from it an element of order $n$?

Comment: So the element $ g^k $ has order n. Am I right?

Comment: Yep. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:G\rightarrow G'$ the morphism. Let $y\in G'$ which has order $n$ and $x\in G$ with $p(x)=y$,  the subgroup $H$ of $G$ generated by $x$ is a cyclic group whose  order $pn$ in fact $|H|=|kerf_{\mid H}|n$, $x^p$ has order $n$.

Comment: By p you mean any integer, is it?

Comment: it is the cardinal of the kernel  restriction of          $f:G\rightarrow G'$ to the subgroup  generated by $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ and the order of $y$ is $n$.

Comment: You seem to denote your homomorphism by $p$ and other times by $f$.